# Avoid crash after doing mmap() on a file that is unmounted

Tags: c, unix, kernel, mmap

I'm doing mmap() on a file that can be unmounted ( the file is located on an USB device which the user can remove at any time ), and my application crashes if the file is unmounted and then i try to access any element in the buffer.

Any solutions to this ?

Answer (score 8):

First of all, I would like to say this should serve as a good argument **not to use** `mmap` unnecessarily as an "optimized read" or similar. Aside from device removal, issues like file truncation by other processes can cause accesses to fault with `SIGBUS`.

If you do really need to use `mmap`, you could install a signal handler for `SIGBUS`. Its task should basically be to:

1. Set a global (or thread-local, if your program is multi-threaded) flag that a `SIGBUS` occurred, so the faulting code can be aware.
2. Call `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` to map a new anonymous page over top of the faulting page. Optionally fill it with data which will be recognized by the code accessing the map as erroneous; this could make step 1 unnecessary.

An alternative approach would be to set a global (or thread-local) `jmp_buf` before accessing the map, and have the signal handler simply call `longjmp`.

Note that neither `mmap` nor `longjmp` is async-signal-safe, but the `SIGBUS` in question is not an asynchronous signal (although it should perhaps be considered one if the faulting access happened inside a non-async-signal-safe library function such as `sscanf`). As long as it's your own code, and not library functions, accessing the map, you should be safe with either. And `mmap` is async-signal-safe in most/all real-world implementations, so you should be okay with the first solution in practice even if it's not formally correct.

Comment: Would phrase it like that: there's more to `mmap` than meets the eye - because error handling is far more complex than for traditional I/O. That's not necessarily a reason _against using_`mmap` ... just be aware of the spirits you summon ;-)

Comment: And make sure they don't fly out of your nose.. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing is to set up a signal handler that will check for accesses to memory locations that correspond to `mmap`ed addresses.

You would use the `sigaction` form of signal handlers, rather than the simpler `signal` handlers as `sigaction` handlers receive information in the `struct __siginfo *` parameter corresponding to the address of the signal. This can be checked to see if it is within the address range of the `mmap`ed file.

`mmap` is great when you don't want to deal with the complications of buffer reading/writing of data, but you only get one form of error (a signal) due to something going wrong. with the `read`/`write` mechanism, you can get the `errno` and determine what happened. It is very much a developer choice in this case.

To jump to a location after receiving the signal then you will need to make use of the `setjmp` and `longjmp`/`siglongjmp` - see some use of this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715413/longjmp-from-signal-handler)

Answer (score -2):

Do not access a file that is not available. Check whether the file is still there, or use a file which cannot be unmounted.

Comment: I don't think that's very helpful due to possible race conditions. Would it help to expect and catch `SIGBUS` around the code accessing the mapped region? Or something similar?

Comment: No. `SIGBUS` is not necessarily recoverable, although some implementations retry the faulting instruction after return from the handler.

Comment: @SimonRichter You don't need to retry the faulting instruction, you only need to determine you can't proceed with a read/write, after which you cease attempts to access the region and return to the caller with some error indication. Perhaps `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` would be able to avoid reexecution of the faulting instruction.

Comment: @SimonRichter: SIGBUS is recoverable. You can either `longjmp` out (could be messy), or (much easier) `mmap` with `MAP_FIXED` a new anonymous map over top of the faulting page.

Comment: @R.. not on all platforms. Many do retry the faulting instruction on return from the handler, which allows creating a new mapping as you suggest, but that is not an universal guarantee.

Answer (score -2):

you can get notification about any change on file(s), dir(s) by using http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify.
you may consider using IN_DELETE.

Comment: Will those notifications will be as immediate as page faults that the OP is trying to curb? If not, don't bother.

Comment: It appears that you have to call `read()` to find out if there have been any changes, but the changes may happen between `read()` returning nothing of interest and the following memory access. It's a race condition. Also, the event queue may overflow. So, this isn't a solution.