# How to read in a large metadata file into an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, memory, buffer

I am currently coding a search algorithm to find all of the cases of a specific byte (char) array found in the metadata of a video. I am trying to load all of the contents of a very large file (about 2GB) into an array, but I keep getting a bad_alloc() exception when I run the program because of the size of the file.

I think one solution would be to create a buffer in order to "chunk" the contents of the file, but I am not sure how to go about coding this.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
string file = "metadata.ts";
ifstream fl(file);  
fl.seekg(0, ios::end);  
size_t len = fl.tellg(); 
char *byteArray = new char[len];
fl.seekg(0, ios::beg); 
fl.read(byteArray, len); 
fl.close();
```

It works for smaller video files, but when I try a file that's slightly under 2GB, it crashes with a bad_alloc() exception.

Thanks in advance for any help - I'm open to all solutions.

EDIT:
I have already checked out the other solutions on Stack OverFlow, and they are not exactly what I'm looking for. I am trying to "chunk" the data and use a buffer to put it into an array, which is not what the other solutions are doing.

Comment: Try it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751873/how-to-read-huge-file-in-c

Comment: Why are you searching for it? I would write something like `std::find(std::istream_iterator<char>(filestream), {}, wanted_byte);`

Comment: I don't think you need C++ for that at all. 'grep' command has one of the best search algorithms available **without** reading whole file (!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629749/how-does-grep-run-so-fast

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read huge file in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34751873/how-to-read-huge-file-in-c)

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ memory mapped I/O".